# Google cloud sql database error: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: 'mydb.register' in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to connect to a Google cloud SQL instance from NodeJS with the following code:

```js
var con = mysql.createConnection({
   password:process.env.GOOGLE_SQL_PASSWORD,
   user:process.env.GOOGLE_SQL_USER,
   database :process.env.GOOGLE_SQL_DATABASE,
   port:3306, 
   host: 'localhost' 
   // socketPath:'/cloudsql/process.env.GOOGLE_INSTANCE_NAME
});
```

Trying to use a socket throws the error `ENOENT EROOR`, thus I'm connecting via port.

I can connect from my local machine (using the command line) to Google cloud sql successfully  and see my database and tables.

When I run my code it's errors with `ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: 'mydb.register'`

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Google App Engine Standard [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#configuring) connecting through TCP is not supported. 
If you have the service account configured it should suffice.